# bit manipulation:print the next smallest and largest numbers with same no of 1 bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

**Given an integer , print the next smallest and next largest number that have the same number of 1 bits in their binary representation**

After Counting the number of 1's in the number.How to determine the next smallest number?

Comment: So, is this homework? (I only ask since this is the second question of this type you've asked)

Comment: no... go ahead to answer it..;)

Comment: let say we have n = 0x11001101, x is next smallest. that means x is greater than n && x is the smallest among all greater && x has the same number of 1 bits as x does. Here is my rule to change from n to x: change the last 0 to 1; if it has 1 bits in the right, change the one most close to the last 0 to 0; otherwise, change the first 0 to 1, change the first 0's most close 1 to 0. I can see recursive way here. but still not clear about the fundamental law or theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for next high you can use Hakmem 175 :

ITEM 175 (Gosper):

To get the next higher number with the same number of 1 bits:

```
unsigned nexthi_same_count_ones(unsigned a) {
   /* works for any word length */
 unsigned c = (a & -a);
 unsigned r = a+c;
  return (((r ^ a) >> 2) / c) | r;
}
```

For next lower I do not know a fast algorithm so I would use the classic approach, if the number is > then 2^0+2^1+...2^n then deduct one from your number and count the number of bits. The first number with n bits is the one.

Comment: oops ... `nexthi_same_count_ones(0)`

Comment: Can you please explain it a little more about the algorithm? for example, what does each calculation mean

Comment: @Dumitrescu : I have a doubt, Most of the scenarios (specially in C) If we perform & operation on a number with its contemprary( - applied on that number). It will always render 1. Can we directly divide ((r^a) >> 2) by 1. Why do I need to compute that operation? Its just my doubt. Sorry if I dont understand something.

Comment: Bad variable naming and no explanation. You've made it way too hard to understand what is happening here.

Comment: Well it's not my code, and the names are not mine. This is a "bit hack" for which I gave the source. Hackmem 175. It's take it or leave it.

Answer (score 7):

For the smaller

```
int getNextSmaller(int num) {
    return ~getNextLarger(~num);
}
```

Sometimes, things is just that simple. :)

http://www.sureinterview.com/shwqst/40004

Comment: The link is broken. And how did you arrive at this? Please add an example

Comment: @NikunjBanka https://web.archive.org/web/20110228051833/http://www.sureinterview.com/shwqst/40004

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.slideshare.net/gkumar007/bits-next-higher-presentation) is a very good explanation. :)

Comment: If you could, try and summarize the explanation in your answer.  Links break, and then your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 1):

See for the sample number 156 below.  I have also posted the source for detailed explanation.

{

```
x = 156
10011100 becomes 10100011  
To get the next higher number we need to set the 6th bit from LSB and shift
the string of 1's (3rd,4th,5th) to LSB positions 1,2 and drop 5th bit
```

so we get 163 - 10100011, which is next highest number with same number of 1's as 156.

```
00011100 - right most string of 1's in x
00000011 - right shifted pattern except left most bit ------> [A]
00010000 - isolated left most bit of right most 1's pattern
00100000 - shiftleft-ed the isolated bit by one position ------> [B]
10000000 - left part of x, excluding right most 1's pattern ------> [C]
10100000 - add B and C (OR operation) ------> [D]
10100011 - add A and D which is required number 163
```

}

{

```
uint_t snoob(uint_t x)
{
    uint_t rightOne;
    uint_t nextHigherOneBit;
    uint_t rightOnesPattern;
    uint_t next = 0;

    if(x){
        // right most set bit
        rightOne = x & -(signed)x;
        // reset the pattern and set next higher bit
        // left part of x will be here
        nextHigherOneBit = x + rightOne;
        // nextHigherOneBit is now part [D] of the above explanation.
        // isolate the pattern
        rightOnesPattern = x ^ nextHigherOneBit;
        // right adjust pattern
        rightOnesPattern = (rightOnesPattern)/rightOne;
        // correction factor
        rightOnesPattern >>= 2;
        // rightOnesPattern is now part [A] of the above explanation.
        // integrate new pattern (Add [D] and [A])
        next = nextHigherOneBit | rightOnesPattern;
    }
    return next;
}
```

}

source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-higher-number-with-same-number-of-set-bits/

Comment: `-(signed)x` is a bad idea, it's paradoxically negating *signed* integers that is dangerous and negating unsigned integers that is safe and well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about the algorithm is to express it algebraically.
Assuming that there is at least one bit set, the input takes the form (...)01[1..][0..], that is some high order bits,
a zero followed by one or more ones followed by zero or more zeros. We just want to shift that first one to the left and the remaining ones below it all the way to the right leaving the high order bits alone.

If we call the high order part H, and have N ones followed by M zeros. In
general, a sequence of N ones can be written as 2<sup>N</sup> - 1 and if followed by M zeros, you just need to multiply by 2<sup>M</sup> so,
this can be written as:

x == H + (2<sup>N</sup> - 1) * 2<sup>M</sup> == H + 2<sup>M+N</sup> - 2<sup>M</sup>

The answer will then take the form:

y == H + 2<sup>M+N</sup> + 2<sup>N-1</sup> - 1

If you take the difference, you can see the function we are trying to compute is simply:

y = x + 2<sup>M</sup> + 2<sup>N-1</sup> - 1

The value 2<sup>M</sup> is simply the low-order bit of x, which can be obtained using the x&-x trick (assuming twos-complement integer representation), so

lowbit = x&-x (2<sup>M</sup>)

Adding that to x gives you the high part of the answer

hi = x + lowbit      == H + 2<sup>M+N</sup>

If take the XOR of hi and x, the H term will cancel out and you are left with the original low-order one sequence plus the shifted bit:

changed = x ^ hi     == 2<sup>N+1</sup> - 2<sup>M</sup>

Dividing by 2<sup>M</sup> gets you to:

w = changed/lowbit      == 2<sup>N+1</sup> - 1

Shifting by 2 more (dividing by 2<sup>2</sup>) gets you the low order part:

lo = w>>2     == 2<sup>N-1</sup> -1

y = hi | low